# Limit and infinite sums. Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^3 x-k^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Could anyone help me with this problem. Compute 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k^3 x-k^2}$$ I don't know how to change a limit and a sum. Could you help me with this problem then suggest me some materials about changing a limit and a sum. Thanks.

Comment: You should look at the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Answer (score 8):

Squeezing is a fast and easy option. For any $x>1$ we have:
$$0\leq \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^3 x-k^2}\leq \frac{1}{x-1}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^3} = \frac{\zeta(3)}{x-1}$$
so the limit is zero.

Answer (score 5):

One may notice that your initial series admits a closed form.

**Step 1.** For $x$ sufficiently great, by partial fraction decomposition, you have
$$\frac{1}{k^3x-k^2}=-\frac{1}{k^2}+x\left(-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k-\frac 1x}\right) , \quad k\geq1.\tag1$$

**Step 2.** Recall that the digamma function admits the following [series representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7)
$$\begin{equation} 
\psi(x+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{x+k}  
\right), \quad x >-1, \tag2
\end{equation}
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

**Step 3.** Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, you get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3x-k^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\gamma \:x - x \:\psi\left(1-\frac 1x\right)\tag3$$

**Step 4.** *For $x$ sufficiently great*, you have the following [asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7)
$$\psi\left(1-\frac 1x\right)=-\gamma -\frac{\pi^2}{6\:x}-\frac{\zeta (3)}{x^2}-\frac{\zeta (4)}{x^3} +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{x^4}\right)\tag4$$

> **Step 5.** As $x \to \infty$, you get the following asymptotic expansion
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3x-k^2}=\frac{\zeta (3)}{x}+\frac{\pi^4}{90 \:x^2} +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)\tag5$$

and your desired limit is equal to $0$.

**Remark.** One may directly obtain $(5)$, just by writing
$$
\frac{1}{k^3x-k^2}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{k^3\left(1-\frac 1{x k}\right)}=\frac 1{x \:k^3}+\frac 1{x^2 \:k^4}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{x^3 \: k^5}\right)
$$ and summing by the use of normal convergence on $x \in [a,+\infty)$, $a>1$.

Answer (score 3):

Choosing $x>1$ and considering the uniform convergence, we have that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k^3 x-k^2}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^3 x-k^2}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

In your Task you have applied

(i) at first a sum

(ii) then the Limit.

When you Change a sum with the Limit it means that you will have

(i) at first the Limit

(ii) then the sum.

You will end up with a sum over $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f_x(k)$ for any Expression $f_x(k)$.